# Number of consecutive rows in grouping

Tags: t-sql

I have a table **Samples** which contains samples of product prices. Note ascending date order.

```
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  Id | Product_Id | Price | Status|    Date     |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 |          1 |   400 |     0 | 1404656325  |
|  2 |          2 |   300 |     0 | 1404657325  |
|  3 |          3 |   100 |     0 | 1404658325  |
|  4 |          1 |   400 |     0 | 1404659325  |
|  5 |          2 |   300 |     0 | 1404660325  |
|  6 |          3 |   100 |     1 | 1404661325  |
|  7 |          1 |   500 |     1 | 1404662325  |
|  8 |          2 |   500 |     0 | 1404663325  |
|  9 |          3 |   500 |     1 | 1404664325  |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I am interested in grouping Product_Id's such that I have a list of unique product ids along with the latest price (that is biggest date).

This is somewhat the classic greatest-n-per-group problem, but in addition I also want a number column that displays how many consecutive rows the *Status* column has been the same starting from oldest date.

So considering my example table above, I should end up having

```
+------------+-------+-----------------+
| Product_Id | Price | SameStatus      |
+------------+-------+-----------------+
|          1 |   500 |               1 |
|          2 |   500 |               3 |
|          3 |   500 |               2 |
+------------+-------+-----------------+
```

I hope it is clear what I want to achieve and there is a friendly person willing to guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.
The approach makes use of [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;WITH Samples (Id, Product_Id, Price, [Status], [Date]) AS 
(
    SELECT 1, 1, 400, 0, 1404656325 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 2, 300, 0, 1404657325 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 3, 100, 0, 1404658325 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, 400, 0, 1404659325 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 2, 300, 0, 1404660325 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 3, 100, 1, 1404661325 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 1, 500, 1, 1404662325 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 2, 500, 0, 1404663325 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 3, 500, 1, 1404664325 
)
,NumberingLogic AS
(
    SELECT   *
            ,SameStatus = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Id, [Status] ORDER BY [Date])
            ,MaxPrice   = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Id ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM Samples
)
SELECT   Product_Id
        ,Price
        ,SameStatus
FROM NumberingLogic 
WHERE MaxPrice = 1
```

PS.
How your dates work is a little unclear to me, but I have used them to order by

Comment: Thank you very much.
The dates are just unix timestamps for simplicity, not how I store it in db in reality.